# Father's Research

Tags: knowledge, science

My father is a scientist, and he's just asked me to help sort some of his cases in the spirit of Science Fortnight! However, all that is written are the following equations (he's not a mathematician):

> Owl monkeys = 1
> Dolphins = 1
> Australian sea lions = 1
>
> Tigers = 2
> Horses = 2
>
> Kangaroos = 3
> Ferrets = 3
>
> Goldfish = 4
> Caribou = 4
>
> Pigeons = 5
> Butterflies = 5
>
> XXXXXXXXXXXX = 16

What is this missing animal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it a

> Mantis Shrimp ?  I sorted it based on number of color receptors.    [mantis shrimp carry 16 types of colour receptive cones.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mantis_shrimp#Eyes)

> [Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_vision#In_other_animal_species)  [image]

Comment: Much quicker than I expected

Comment: google is our best friend ;)

Comment: I'm presuming the owl monkey and Australian sea lion gave it away? Most of the others weren't very specific (just want some feedback)

Comment: No [pigeons and butterflies](https://www.google.com/search?q=pigeons+and+butterflies+have) gave me Pentachromacy, then . . .. @Inazuma

Comment: Hmm... not bad.